# SharePoint 2016 On-Premise multi server farm migration from one domain to another

Tags: sharepoint-server, domain

We are planning to migrate from one domain ABC to XYZ for our SharePoint 2016 farm which has 3 app servers and 4 web servers, what is the approach and steps that I need to follow for this. any suggestions would be really helpful. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a brand new farm with new service accounts, then perform a data migration (i.e. content database/service app database backup/restore, full farm backup, etc.).

It is not supported to migrate virtual machines running SharePoint between domains.

Comment: Hi Trevor thanks for the suggestions , are there any documentations online on how to approach on this.